# Can't seem to call a custom dialog from the mainWindow. PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qt-designer

I need to call a form(custom dialog designed with QtDesigner) through the slot of a button on the Main Window(also on QtDesigned, hence seperate file). Below is the relevant code:

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

    self.setupUi(self)

    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.my_func)


def my_func(self):
    form = Form_UI.Custom_Dialog()

    if form.exec_():
        print "successfully opened"
```

How ever I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\myPath\code.py", line 27, in my_func
if form.exec_():
AttributeError: 'Custom_Dialog' object has no attribute 'exec_'
```

I don't understand, because the following code(using built-in Dialog) works just fine:

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

    self.setupUi(self)

    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.my_func)


def my_func(self):
    form = QtGui.QDialog()

    if form.exec_():
        print "successfully opened"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class generated by `pyuic4` does not derive from `QDialog`, so if you don't write a python class for that ui file as you did for the main window, you need to create a `QDialog` object and a ui class object:

```
def my_func(self):
   form = QtGui.QDialog()
   ui_form = Form_UI.Custom_Dialog()
   ui_form.setupUi(form)     

   if form.exec_():
       print "successfully opened"
```

Comment: But, I have to ask, what would be the better practice (or convention), deriving it in the ui file or setting up as above?

Comment: @Ryan Since you can't edit the generated file because any changes would be lost when calling pyuic4 again, I assume you meant "... writing a class that would derive from both `QDialog` and `Custom_Dialog` or setting up as above". There is no PyQt convention to choose between these 2 methods except the general ["single responsibility rule"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), so, basically, if you don't need to add any logic to the generated dialog (relatively complex user interaction or validation...), the above code should be enough.